# How deselect a item on a List with F#/xamarin.forms that need to Navigation.PushAsync?

Tags: listview, f#, xamarin.forms

I have a list that act as a menu.

When selected the item, it navigate to the detail form. It use `rootPage.Navigation.PushAsync`.

However, after the navigation the item stay selected. I need to deselect it so when the user go back it can use the menu again.

This is my try:

```
let selectCell title (e:SelectedItemChangedEventArgs) form =
    let form = form(e.SelectedItem)

    Async.AwaitTask(rootPage.Navigation.PushAsync(form, true)) |> Async.Ignore |> ignore

let selectedDeuda (e:SelectedItemChangedEventArgs) =
    selectCell "Deuda" e editFormDeuda

....
....
data.ItemSelected.Add( fun e -> selectedDeuda(e); data.SelectedItem <- null)
```

However, the .SelectedItem become null before the selectCell finish...